# How to enable chrome driver on Azure notebook for scraping

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to enable chrome driver on Azure(notebooks.azure.com)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
#driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
```

got below error "WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home"

I already installed chrome driver in my azure server. is notebook and azure vm is independent of each other